# Redux state changes introduced by one component do not reflect on other components that use useSelector hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have since modified my code to focus on the problem so its more easier to understand by whoever attempts to help.

**Scenario**

I have a redux store created with Redux toolkit with a slice named 'asts' and initialized with 'astsTestData' array.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { astsData, astsTestData } from "../data/astsData/astsData";

const astsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "asts",
    initialState: { astsData, astsTestData },
    reducers: {
        astCreated: (state, action) => {
            state.astsData.push(action.payload);
        },
        astUpdated: (state, action) => {},
        astDeleted: (state, action) => {},
        astTestDataCreated: (state, action) => {
            console.log(`astTestDataCreated running`);
            console.log(`state.astsTestData`, state.astsTestData);
            console.log(`action`, action);
            return {
                ...state,
                astsTestData: [...astsTestData, action.payload],
            };

            // state.astsTestData.push(action.payload)
        },
    },
});

// console.log(`astsSlice`, astsSlice)

export const { astCreated, astUpdated, astDeleted, astTestDataCreated } =
    astsSlice.actions;

export default astsSlice.reducer;
```

I have another slice named 'sch'. This slice stores rgv data.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { poData, splData, grvData } from "../data/schData/schData";

const schSlice = createSlice({
    name: "sch",
    initialState: { poData, splData, grvData },
    reducers: {
        // Purchase Order reducers
        // Goods receiving reducers
        grvCreated: (state, action) => {
            console.log(`grvCreated running`);
            console.log(`state.grvData`, state.grvData);
            console.log(`action`, action);
            state.grvData.push(action.payload);
        },
        grvUpdated: (state, action) => {},
        grvDeleted: (state, action) => {},
    },
});

// console.log(`schSlice`, schSlice);

export const {
    poCreated,
    poUpdated,
    poDeleted,
    popCreated,
    popUpdated,
    popDeleted,
    grvCreated,
    grvUpdated,
    grvDeleted,
} = schSlice.actions;

export default schSlice.reducer;
```

I have a react component called 'Sch' that displays 'sch.grvData' on a ag-grid table. 'Sch uses 'ag-grid' on a component called 'GrvTestTable' to display 'sch.rgvData' acquired using useSelctor. This part works well all the time.

```
import React from "react";
import GrvTestAddAstBtn from "../../components/forms/grvForm/grvTest/GrvTestAddAstBtn";
import GrvTestTable from "../../components/forms/grvForm/grvTest/GrvTestTable";

const Sch = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sch">
            <GrvTestTable /> 
            <GrvTestAddAstBtn /> 
        </div>
    );
};
export default Sch;
```

The   table displays 'sch.grvData' records that are created via dispatch from "handlSubmit" on grv form .

```
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();;
        // dispatch data to 'sch.grvData'
        dispatch(grvCreated(grvFormData));
        // dispatch data to 'asts.astsTestData'
        dispatch(
            astTestDataCreated({
                astId: nanoid(),
                grvId: grvFormData.grvId,
                astCartegory: grvFormData.grvAstCartegory,
                astNo: grvFormData.grvAstNo,
            })
        );
        setModalOpened(false);
        setGrvFormData([]);
        setComponentToOpen("");
    };
```

From 'Sch', besides the ag grid table, there is a   button used to open the 'grv form' where on submission the grv form data is written into the 'sch.rgvData' that's on in redux store after which, same data is used to create a new asts record on 'asts.astsTestData'.

I have another component called 'TestAstTable' that displays the 'asts.astsTestData' using ag data grid table. This is where the problem is.

Both my ag-grid tables ( and  ) receive data from the grid store via useSelector.

**TestAstTable**

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react"; // the AG Grid React Component

import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Core grid CSS, always needed
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"; // Optional theme CSS

import "react-tippy/dist/tippy.css";
import { useSelector, useStore } from "react-redux";

const TestAstsTable = () => {

  const { astsTestData } = useSelector(state => state.asts)
    console.log(`astsTestData`, astsTestData);
  
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(astsTestData)

  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: "astId" },
    { field: "grvId" },
    { field: "astCartegory" },
    { field: "astNo"},
  ])

    useEffect(() => {
        setRowData(astsTestData);
    }, [astsTestData]);
    

    const gridRef = useRef(); 
    const defaultColDef = useMemo(
        () => ({
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            resizable: true,
        }),
        []
    );

    // console.log(`rowData`, rowData);

    return (
        <div className={`ag-theme-alpine `}>
            <AgGridReact
                ref={gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API
                rowData={rowData} // Row Data for Rows
                columnDefs={columnDefs} // Column Defs for Columns
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef} // Default Column Properties
                animateRows={true} // Optional - set to 'true' to have rows animate when sorted
                rowSelection="single" // Options - allows click selection of rows
                domLayout={"autoHeight"}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestAstsTable;

// TODO: mouse over tips on the TestAstsTable skipHeader
```

**GrvTestTable**

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react"; // the AG Grid React Component

import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Core grid CSS, always needed
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"; // Optional theme CSS

import "react-tippy/dist/tippy.css";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const GrvTestTable = () => {
    const { grvData } = useSelector(state => state.sch);
    console.log(`grvData`, grvData);

    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(grvData);

    useEffect(() => {
        setRowData(grvData)
    }, [grvData]);

    const [columnDefs] = useState([
        { field: "grvId" },
        { field: "grvAstCartegory" },
        { field: "grvAstNo" },
    ]);

    const gridRef = useRef();
    const defaultColDef = useMemo(
        () => ({
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            resizable: true,
        }),
        []
    );

    // console.log(`rowData`, rowData);

    return (
        <div className={`ag-theme-alpine `}>
            <AgGridReact
                ref={gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API
                rowData={rowData} // Row Data for Rows
                columnDefs={columnDefs} // Column Defs for Columns
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef} // Default Column Properties
                animateRows={true} // Optional - set to 'true' to have rows animate when sorted
                rowSelection="single" // Options - allows click selection of rows
                domLayout={"autoHeight"}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default GrvTestTable;
```

Every time a new 'grv record' is created on 'sch.grvData', there is an ast record created on the 'asts.astsTestData'. This is done on form submit handler (handleSubmit) from 'grv form'.

Through redux devtools, I can can confirm that the store gets updated after I dispatch the action payload from the form submit. Via redux dev tools I can see that both 'sch.rgvData' and 'asts.astsTestData' are updated.

With redux toolkit immer, I'm able to use array push for both 'sch.rgvData' (state.grvData.push(action.payload)) and 'asts.astsTestData' (state.astsTestData.push(action.payload)) in my reducers to update the immutable sate.

**Problem**

'**TestAstTable**' table component which uses useSelctor to acquire redux state.astsTestData **DOES NOT** update but the '**GrvTestTable**' does update on every grv form submission.

**Efforts I've tried to solve the problem**

1. I've looked all over the web in vain
2. I've tried useState and useEffect to trigger rerender when astsTestData updates but this does not work.
3. I've looked to see if I'm not mutating the store, and I am NOT
4. I thought the problem mmay be immutability so I tried on reducers to use old way with immer, no luck. With immer I to push the acton payload on the array. With the old way I used object spread operator. no luck.
5. I verified that I'm using only one store

**Some weird observations**

When I look at 'asts' redux page using redux dev tools I don't see updated asts state in redux store, but when I look at 'Sch' redux page using redux dev tools I do see both 'sch.grvData' and 'asts.astsTestData' updated state in redux store. This left me very confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you out without a reproducible example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) etc.

Comment: Ok …I’ll share all code